# Deep copy object properties (including those with private setter) to another object of the same type

Tags: c#, properties, copy

I have done some research and only found "superficial" methods that actually copy your properties from one object to another, such as:

```
public static void CopyPropertiesTo<T, TU>(this T source, TU dest)
{
    var sourceProps = typeof(T).GetProperties().Where(x => x.CanRead).ToList();
    var destProps = typeof(TU).GetProperties()
        .Where(x => x.CanWrite)
        .ToList();
    foreach (var sourceProp in sourceProps)
    {
        if (destProps.Any(x => x.Name == sourceProp.Name))
        {
            var p = destProps.First(x => x.Name == sourceProp.Name);
            if (p.CanWrite)
            { // check if the property can be set or no.
                p.SetValue(dest, sourceProp.GetValue(source, null), null);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The problem with the  **above method** is that it **doesn't copy the private fields** too.

I have a class like this:

```
class myType{
    public object prop1;
    private bool flag;
    private otherType prop2; //recursive deep property copy loop needed on this object.

    myType(bool flag){
        this.flag = flag;
    }
}
```

Now let's suppose I will run the above method on these two classes:

```
myType obj1 = new myType(false);
myType obj2 = new myType(true);
obj1.CopyPropertiesTo(obj2);
```

The outcome will be that `obj2.flag` value will **remain unchanged**`.

I am looking for a method that actually *deep* copies all properties including those with private setters.

Comment: private members can't be copied AFAIK

Comment: @Rahul bad to know. What would other alternatives be? I need to keep the *same reference* of the object in my environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because `Type.GetProperties` only returns properties.  What you are searching for is essentially the same code as the `CopyPropertiesTo` above, but you want to replace `GetProperties` with `GetFields`.  You also need to specify `BindingFlags` in the parameters of the method to get private members.

Try this out:

```
public static void CopyFieldsTo<T, TU>(this T source, TU dest)
{
    var sourceFields = typeof(T).GetFields(BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance).ToList();
    var destFields = typeof(TU).GetFields(BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance).ToList();
    foreach (var sourceField in sourceFields)
    {
        if (destFields.Any(x => x.Name == sourceField.Name))
        {
            var f = destFields.First(x => x.Name == sourceField.Name);
            f.SetValue(dest, sourceField.GetValue(source));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is `BindingFlags.Instance` needed for in this case?

Comment: It indicates that the search should include instance members.  Without it, the search will return nothing.

Comment: Is it needed when performing `GetProperties` aswell?

Comment: If you specify custom bindings then I believe so yes.  It certainly doesn't hurt, as you only want instance members anyway.